# Node.js tool to update Cisco UCCX with CSV data

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, rest, ecmascript-8

What this tool does update skills for agents on a Contact Center Cluster (Cisco UCCX). The tool reads a csv file called agents.csv from the current working directory. This file has a list of agents and their skills.  The skills are updated using [a REST API](https://developer.cisco.com/docs/contact-center-express/#!system-configuration-apis).

Note that UCCX allows a maximum of 400 agents, so that's why I use the sync API for reading a file and csv because I don't think it's going to be performance impacting.

This is the line where the agent skills are updated:

```
        await axios.put(ccxURI, xml, config);
```

It is done sequentially. I originally wanted to do it concurrently using Promise.all but for some reason the UCCX server responds with a 500 error. So for now I'm doing it one at a time.

Code is below:

```
"use strict";

const ora = require("ora");
let throbber;

const inquirer = require("inquirer");

const prompts = [
    {
      name: "IP",
      type: "input",
      message: "Enter IP address of UCCX publisher: ",
    },
    {
        name: "user",
        type: "input",
        message: "Enter username: ",
    },
    {
        name: "pass",
        type: "password",
        message: "Enter password: ",
    },
];

const axios = require("axios");
const https = require("https");


const fs = require("fs");
// csv sync api is used as there can be at most 400 agents on the cluster
// hence it should not be performance impacting
const parse = require("csv-parse/lib/sync");
const parseOptions = {
    comment: "#",
    skip_empty_lines: true,
    trim: true
};

// csv file won"t exceed 1MB so readFileSync should be OK
const csv = fs.readFileSync("agents.csv", "utf-8");
const parser = require("xml2json");

(async () => {
    console.log("Please verify agents.csv is in the current working directory\n");
    const answers = await inquirer.prompt(prompts);

    const IP = answers.IP;
    const config = {
        auth: {
            username: answers.user,
            password: answers.pass
        },
        httpsAgent: new https.Agent({  
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        }),
        headers: {"Content-Type": "application/xml"}
    };

    const XMLtemplate = `
        <resource>
            <self></self>
            <userID></userID>
            <firstName></firstName>
            <lastName></lastName>
            <extension></extension>
            <alias></alias>
            <resourceGroup></resourceGroup>
            <skillMap>
                <skillCompetency></skillCompetency>
            </skillMap>
            <autoAvailable>true</autoAvailable>
            <type></type>
            <team name="Default">
                <refURL>${IP}/adminapi/team/1</refURL>
            </team>
            <primarySupervisorOf/>
            <secondarySupervisorOf/>
        </resource>`;

    const resourceGroupMapping = {};
    const resourceGroupURI = `https://${IP}/adminapi/resourceGroup`;
    const resourceGroupList = await axios.get(resourceGroupURI, config); 

    throbber = ora("Updating").start();
    for(const resourceGroup of resourceGroupList.data.resourceGroup) {
        resourceGroupMapping[resourceGroup.name] = resourceGroup.id;
    }

    const skillMapping = {};
    const skillURI = `https://${IP}/adminapi/skill`; 
    const skillList = await axios.get(skillURI, config);

    for(const skill of skillList.data.skill) {
        skillMapping[skill.skillName] = skill.skillId;
    }

    const teamMapping = {};
    const teamURI = `https://${IP}/adminapi/team`;
    const teamList = await axios.get(teamURI, config); 

    for(const team of teamList.data.team) {
        teamMapping[team.teamname] = team.teamId;
    }

    // sample csv
    // #id,firstName,lastName,extension,resourceGroup,team,skill1,competence1,skill2,competence2,skill3,competence3,skill4,competence4 ... 
    // Adrian_A,Adrian,Aldana,1008,1,Saturday-Lending,Lending,Pre_Approved_Loans,9,HELOC,6,Auto_and_Consumer_Loans,4,Loan_Status,7
    const records = parse(csv, parseOptions);
    const recordLength = records.length;

    const XMLOptions = {
        object: true,
        reversible: true,
        trim: true
    };

    for(let index = 0; index < recordLength; index++) {
        let skillsAndCompetency;
        let jsonObject;
        let xml;
        let ccxURI;

        jsonObject = parser.toJson(XMLtemplate, XMLOptions);
        jsonObject.resource.skillMap.skillCompetency = [];

        jsonObject.resource.self = { "$t" : `https://${IP}/adminapi/resource/${records[index][0]}` };
        jsonObject.resource.userID = { "$t" : `${records[index][0]}` };
        jsonObject.resource.firstName = { "$t" : `${records[index][1]}` };
        jsonObject.resource.lastName = { "$t" : `${records[index][2]}` };
        jsonObject.resource.extension = { "$t" : `${records[index][3]}` };

        // include resource type
        jsonObject.resource.type = { "$t" : `${records[index][4]}` };

        // update resource group
        if(records[index][5]) {
            jsonObject.resource.resourceGroup.name = `${records[index][5]}`;
            jsonObject.resource.resourceGroup.refURL = { "$t" : `https://${IP}/adminapi/resourceGroup/${resourceGroupMapping[records[index][5]]}` };
        }

        // update team
        if(records[index][6] !== "Default") {
            jsonObject.resource.team.name = records[index][6];
            jsonObject.resource.team.refURL = { "$t" : `https://${IP}/adminapi/team/${teamMapping[records[index][6]]}` };
        }

        // update all skills and competency 
        for(let j = 7; j < records[index].length; j += 2) {
            skillsAndCompetency = { 
                    competencelevel : "",
                    skillNameUriPair : { 
                        name: "",
                        refURL : ""
                    }
            };

            skillsAndCompetency.competencelevel = { "$t" : `${records[index][j + 1]}` };
            skillsAndCompetency.skillNameUriPair.name = `${records[index][j]}`;
            skillsAndCompetency.skillNameUriPair.refURL = { "$t" : `https://${IP}/adminapi/skill/${skillMapping[records[index][j]]}` };
            jsonObject.resource.skillMap.skillCompetency.push(skillsAndCompetency);
        }

        // xml payload 
        xml = `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>` + parser.toXml(JSON.stringify(jsonObject));

        // update skills for the agents
        ccxURI = `https://${IP}/adminapi/resource/${records[index][0]}`;
        // if a row in the csv is incorrect, continue processing subsequent rows
        try {
            await axios.put(ccxURI, xml, config);
        } catch (error) {
            throbber.stop();
            console.log(`\nCould not assign skills to ${records[index][0]}\n${error.response.data.apiError[0].errorMessage}\n`);
            throbber.start();
        }
    }
})()
    .catch(error => console.log(error.stack))
    .then( () => throbber.stop());
```